# I can't stop sound with C# Form(SpVoice)

Tags: c#

I'm developing a dictionary. I can listening for words in dictionary. if we quickly listening a lot of words. without listening the old words I cannot listen the currently selected word. So I am waiting listen to the selected word.
'''

```
class Voicer1
{
    public string read;
    public SpVoice Sound_SV = new SpVoice();
    public Thread th_WP;
    public void Sound_Stp(string vocalist)
    {           
        read = vocalist.ToString();
        thread_Stp();
    }
    public void thread_Stp()
    {
        th_WP = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sound_1));
        th_WP.Start();               
    }
    public void sound_1()
    {           
        Sound_SV.Speak(read.ToString(), SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
 }
```

This is listening

```
 Voicer1 Sound_1= new Voicer1();
Snd.Sound_Stp(label1.Text.ToString());
```

I use where necessary;

```
SoundPlayer stoprrr= new SoundPlayer();
stoprrr.Stop();
```

But this doesn't work.

Can you help me

Comment: Does the `SpVoice` type have a Stop method or something similar?

Comment: SpVoice doesn't have stop method and i tried pause,resume,volume but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use;
`using System.Speech.Synthesis;`
then,                                                                   `SpeechSynthesizer SSObj;`                                                                                                                                               When I want to listen to the new word,

```
    if (SSObj!= null)
    {
        SSObj.Dispose();
    }

SSObj= new SpeechSynthesizer();
SSObj.SpeakAsync(read);
```

This method worked.